# Wordpress error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I'm having a problem with setting feature image, I am using the similar submit several times in the same page to submit post outside the admin area and not getting any errors, only this submit form.

After tracing errors report I found the problem with `_get_non_cached_ids` function which is in `wp-includes/functions.php on line 3816` (twentyeleven theme)

Error says: `Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int`

When I test it I got that `it is not int`, then I try to discover the function casing that error

Below the `_get_non_cached_ids` function with my test code

```
/**
 * Retrieve ids that are not already present in the cache
 *
 * @since 3.4.0
 *
 * @param array $object_ids ID list
 * @param string $cache_key The cache bucket to check against
 *
 * @return array
 */
function _get_non_cached_ids( $object_ids, $cache_key ) {
    $clean = array();
    foreach ( $object_ids as $id ) {

        /* my test start */
        if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
            $error_string = $id->get_error_message();
            echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $error_string . '</p></div>';
            exit; 
        }else{
            echo 'id is ok';
            exit;
        }
        /* my test end */

        $id = (int) $id;
        if ( !wp_cache_get( $id, $cache_key ) ) {
            $clean[] = $id;
        }
    }

    return $clean;
}
```

I tried the code and got a message saying:

`No file was uploaded.`

**HOW NO FILE WAS UPLOADED** even the image uploaded successfully and attached to the post, but it didn't appear as `Featured image`

and in the admin area for edit post I got an error in the Feature image area says:

`Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int in SITE_ROOT/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 4294`

I test if is_int and it was int

**Note that** in the `_get_non_cached_ids`, exit happening only if there is a problem, which means that if there is no problem the code don't enter to `_get_non_cached_ids` function at all

Answer (score 0):

After hundreds of tests every block of my code I got it working, and finally `is_wp_error($id) returns id is ok`

There was unknown error in upload image from PC function which was making conflict with upload image from link, but now it is working, and that's why I was getting error message saying: `No file was uploaded`